# How can I write this jQuery snippet more beautiful

Tags: jquery, events, function

These two functions should be fired on load and on resize. I'm wondering how to write it more compact and beautiful. Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    fullScreen();
    footer();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        fullScreen();
        footer();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can trigger the [resize](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) event right after you register your handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {  // Register handler.
        fullScreen();
        footer();
    }).resize();                   // Trigger event.
});
```

Comment: Triggering an event just to call your own function is...non-optimal to put it mildly.

Comment: @T.J., I suppose you're right. I was aiming for "compact and beautiful" :)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder & @Frédéric Hamidi, why is this non-optimal? because of bad readability? it works and it's compact, for me it's beautiful.

Comment: @Thomasz, well, there could be other handlers registered on the `resize` event, so `fullScreen()` and `footer()` will be called, but other functions might also be called as a side-effect of triggering the event.

Comment: @Thomasz: Seconding what @Frédéric said about other handlers. Also, it's just the long way around, why go through an event chain and fire a synthetic event, just so you can call a function you can call directly? It's just round-about engineering. And as Frédéric says, it has potential negative impacts.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could combine them into one function, but I'm not sure it's more "beautiful":

```
jQuery(function($) {

    both();
    $(window).resize(both);

    function both() {
        fullScreen();
        footer();
    }
});
```

It does address the issue of not repeating yourself.

**Off-topic**: I also switched `$(document).ready(function(){...` to `jQuery(function($){...`. It does the same thing, but makes the quoted code compatible with [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), if that's useful. If you'll never want `noConflict` compatibility, you can use `$(function(){...` instead, but hey, for six extra chars...

Comment: this is maybe more optimal, but in this case I prefer Frédéric Hamidi's more compact answer ;) thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
    function both() {
        fullScreen();
        footer();
    }

    both();
    $(window).resize(both);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

@T.J. Crowder's answer (call to another method) looks to be an ideal solution.

The call to a new method captures the *intention* of the calls to both of those methods, making it **functional**.

Also, if you need to change what to do on load or resize, you wil only have to change it in the one method making it **maintainable**.

A meaningful name e.g. readjustLayoutAfterResize that describes the intention makes it **readable**.

Functional, maintainable and readable is beautiful to me and I'm sure to whoever will maintain it.

Comment: This isn't an answer? This is a comment.

Comment: I thought that too @Marcus and @Tomalak, but since it contains information as to why the approach could meet the criteria of beautiful, it seems more useful as an answer rather than a cramped comment that may not be expanded/read.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var doStuff = function () {
            fullScreen();
            footer();
        };
        doStuff();

        $(window).resize(function () {
            doStuff();
        });
    });
```

Comment: You have 2 unnecessary bits of code, why write a function declaration like that, and why wrap a function call in a call to an anonymous function?